# Github action executes an action one at the end of the other

Tags: github, github-actions, action, commit

I have the following two actions, how can I make the second action be executed at the end of the first after making the first one commit and push?

Action1

```yaml
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
name: Scrape Data
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Build
      run: npm install
    - name: Scrape
      run: npm run action 
    - uses: mikeal/publish-to-github-action@master
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # GitHub sets this for you
```

Action2

```yaml
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
name: Visit Data
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Build
      run: npm install
    - name: Scrape
      run: npm run visit 
    - uses: mikeal/publish-to-github-action@master
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # GitHub sets this for you
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [workflow_run](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) trigger on the second workflow.

**Example:**

```
name: Visit Data

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ['Scrape Data'] # First workflow name 
    types: 
      - completed # can also use 'requested'

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Build
      run: npm install
    - name: Scrape
      run: npm run visit 
    - uses: mikeal/publish-to-github-action@master
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

*Note that you can't use workflow `inputs` in that case (I observed you had it set, and if it's necessary you would need to use another trigger, for example through the Github API using a [workflow dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event) with a payload).*